# How do you migrate a Parse Background Job in light of Parse.com shutting down?

Tags: parse-platform, jobs, dashboard

I have a general question about Parse shutting down in January 2017.  I have migrated my Monogodb instance and have parse server up and running on heroku.

Do we have to migrate the Parse Dashboard to our own server too or will that continue to run on parse.com?  I ask because I currently schedule cloud jobs through that, and haven't been able to figure out how to migrate these Background Jobs, or send on demand push notifications.

Comment: Have you setup the self hosted parse-server? https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/668

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cf http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-the-parse-server-dashboard/ I understand that they want you to migrate to your own self hosted parse dashboard.